# How would you host a private web application only meant for a few users?

Tags: php, laravel, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I want to host a private web app that registers members in a club, however I do not know how to go about hosting it so that the club network can only access it. how do I do this? and how can I scale it up so that it supports other clients who may be using different networks?
any help is appreciated

Comment: other clients who may not be using different networks? is this correct ?

Comment: sorry I have edited it

Answer (score 1):

There are many things you can do:

1. Host the app on one of the club's machines.
2. If using a vps configure the network interface so that the vps is part of the club's network.
3. Use a firewall to block requests from all machines except those from the club's network.

Comment: I think no.2 and 3. would be the best course of action for maintenance purposes